# How do I associate a Parse user with their respective installationId when they log in/sign up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

When a user of my Parse app logs in or signs up, a new `User` object is created in the database with `username`, `password`, and `email` properties, among others. What I want to do is set the `User` object's `installationId` property to be a pointer to the `installationId` property of that devices respective `Installation` object, as can be seen in the screenshot.

I've tried looking through `PFUser.h` to see where it tells the database to set the `User`s `username` and `email` properties, and thought I'd just have it set the `installationId` property from there as well, but I can't seem to find the place where it does this.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**PFUser.h**:

```
// PFUser.h
// Copyright 2011 Parse, Inc. All rights reserved.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PFConstants.h"
#import "PFObject.h"
#import "PFSubclassing.h"

@class PFQuery;

/*!
A Parse Framework User Object that is a local representation of a user persisted to the Parse cloud. This class
 is a subclass of a PFObject, and retains the same functionality of a PFObject, but also extends it with various
 user specific methods, like authentication, signing up, and validation uniqueness.

 Many APIs responsible for linking a PFUser with Facebook or Twitter have been deprecated in favor of dedicated
 utilities for each social network. See PFFacebookUtils and PFTwitterUtils for more information.
 */

@interface PFUser : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

/*! The name of the PFUser class in the REST API. This is a required
 *  PFSubclassing method */
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

/** @name Accessing the Current User */

/*!
 Gets the currently logged in user from disk and returns an instance of it.
 @result Returns a PFUser that is the currently logged in user. If there is none, returns nil.
 */
+ (instancetype)currentUser;

/// The session token for the PFUser. This is set by the server upon successful authentication.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sessionToken;

/// Whether the PFUser was just created from a request. This is only set after a Facebook or Twitter login.
@property (readonly, assign) BOOL isNew;

/*!
 Whether the user is an authenticated object for the device. An authenticated PFUser is one that is obtained via
 a signUp or logIn method. An authenticated object is required in order to save (with altered values) or delete it.
 @result Returns whether the user is authenticated.
 */
- (BOOL)isAuthenticated;

/** @name Creating a New User */

/*!
 Creates a new PFUser object.
 @result Returns a new PFUser object.
 */
+ (PFUser *)user;

/*!
 Enables automatic creation of anonymous users.  After calling this method, [PFUser currentUser] will always have a value.
 The user will only be created on the server once the user has been saved, or once an object with a relation to that user or
 an ACL that refers to the user has been saved.

 Note: saveEventually will not work if an item being saved has a relation to an automatic user that has never been saved.
 */
+ (void)enableAutomaticUser;

/// The username for the PFUser.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *username;

/** 
 The password for the PFUser. This will not be filled in from the server with
 the password. It is only meant to be set.
 */
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *password;

/// The email for the PFUser.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *email;

// The installationId for the PFUser
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *installationId;



/*!
 Signs up the user. Make sure that password and username are set. This will also enforce that the username isn't already taken. 
 @result Returns true if the sign up was successful.
 */
- (BOOL)signUp;

/*!
 Signs up the user. Make sure that password and username are set. This will also enforce that the username isn't already taken.
 @param error Error object to set on error. 
 @result Returns whether the sign up was successful.
 */
- (BOOL)signUp:(NSError **)error;

/*!
 Signs up the user asynchronously. Make sure that password and username are set. This will also enforce that the username isn't already taken.
 */
- (void)signUpInBackground;

/*!
 Signs up the user asynchronously. Make sure that password and username are set. This will also enforce that the username isn't already taken.
 @param block The block to execute. The block should have the following argument signature: (BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) 
 */
- (void)signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block;

/*!
 Signs up the user asynchronously. Make sure that password and username are set. This will also enforce that the username isn't already taken.
 @param target Target object for the selector.
 @param selector The selector that will be called when the asynchrounous request is complete. It should have the following signature: (void)callbackWithResult:(NSNumber *)result error:(NSError **)error. error will be nil on success and set if there was an error. [result boolValue] will tell you whether the call succeeded or not.
 */
- (void)signUpInBackgroundWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;

/** @name Logging in */

/*!
 Makes a request to login a user with specified credentials. Returns an instance
 of the successfully logged in PFUser. This will also cache the user locally so 
 that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 @param username The username of the user.
 @param password The password of the user.
 @result Returns an instance of the PFUser on success. If login failed for either wrong password or wrong username, returns nil.
 */
+ (instancetype)logInWithUsername:(NSString *)username
                         password:(NSString *)password;

/*!
 Makes a request to login a user with specified credentials. Returns an
 instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This will also cache the user 
 locally so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 @param username The username of the user.
 @param password The password of the user.
 @param error The error object to set on error.
 @result Returns an instance of the PFUser on success. If login failed for either wrong password or wrong username, returns nil.
 */
+ (instancetype)logInWithUsername:(NSString *)username
                         password:(NSString *)password
                            error:(NSError **)error;

/*!
 Makes an asynchronous request to login a user with specified credentials.
 Returns an instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This will also cache 
 the user locally so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 @param username The username of the user.
 @param password The password of the user.
 */
+ (void)logInWithUsernameInBackground:(NSString *)username
                             password:(NSString *)password;

/*!
 Makes an asynchronous request to login a user with specified credentials.
 Returns an instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This will also cache 
 the user locally so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user. 
 The selector for the callback should look like: myCallback:(PFUser *)user error:(NSError **)error
 @param username The username of the user.
 @param password The password of the user.
 @param target Target object for the selector.
 @param selector The selector that will be called when the asynchrounous request is complete.
 */
+ (void)logInWithUsernameInBackground:(NSString *)username
                             password:(NSString *)password
                               target:(id)target
                             selector:(SEL)selector;

/*!
 Makes an asynchronous request to log in a user with specified credentials.
 Returns an instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This will also cache 
 the user locally so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user. 
 @param username The username of the user.
 @param password The password of the user.
 @param block The block to execute. The block should have the following argument signature: (PFUser *user, NSError *error) 
 */
+ (void)logInWithUsernameInBackground:(NSString *)username
                             password:(NSString *)password
                                block:(PFUserResultBlock)block;

/** @name Becoming a user */

/*!
 Makes a request to become a user with the given session token. Returns an
 instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This also caches the user locally
 so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 @param sessionToken The session token for the user.
 @result Returns an instance of the PFUser on success. If becoming a user fails due to incorrect token, it returns nil.
 */
+ (instancetype)become:(NSString *)sessionToken;

/*!
 Makes a request to become a user with the given session token. Returns an
 instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This will also cache the user
 locally so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 @param sessionToken The session token for the user.
 @param error The error object to set on error.
 @result Returns an instance of the PFUser on success. If becoming a user fails due to incorrect token, it returns nil.
 */
+ (instancetype)become:(NSString *)sessionToken
                 error:(NSError **)error;

/*!
 Makes an asynchronous request to become a user with the given session token. Returns an
 instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This also caches the user locally
 so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 @param sessionToken The session token for the user.
 */
+ (void)becomeInBackground:(NSString *)sessionToken;

/*!
 Makes an asynchronous request to become a user with the given session token. Returns an
 instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This also caches the user locally
 so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 The selector for the callback should look like: myCallback:(PFUser *)user error:(NSError **)error
 @param sessionToken The session token for the user.
 @param target Target object for the selector.
 @param selector The selector that will be called when the asynchrounous request is complete.
 */
+ (void)becomeInBackground:(NSString *)sessionToken
                    target:(id)target
                  selector:(SEL)selector;

/*!
 Makes an asynchronous request to become a user with the given session token. Returns an
 instance of the successfully logged in PFUser. This also caches the user locally
 so that calls to currentUser will use the latest logged in user.
 The selector for the callback should look like: myCallback:(PFUser *)user error:(NSError **)error
 @param sessionToken The session token for the user.
 @param block The block to execute. The block should have the following argument signature: (PFUser *user, NSError *error)
 */
+ (void)becomeInBackground:(NSString *)sessionToken
                     block:(PFUserResultBlock)block;

/** @name Logging Out */

/*!
 Logs out the currently logged in user on disk.
 */
+ (void)logOut;

/** @name Requesting a Password Reset */

/*!
 Send a password reset request for a specified email. If a user account exists with that email,
 an email will be sent to that address with instructions on how to reset their password.
 @param email Email of the account to send a reset password request.
 @result Returns true if the reset email request is successful. False if no account was found for the email address.
 */
+ (BOOL)requestPasswordResetForEmail:(NSString *)email;

/*!
 Send a password reset request for a specified email and sets an error object. If a user
 account exists with that email, an email will be sent to that address with instructions 
 on how to reset their password.
 @param email Email of the account to send a reset password request.
 @param error Error object to set on error.
 @result Returns true if the reset email request is successful. False if no account was found for the email address.
 */
+ (BOOL)requestPasswordResetForEmail:(NSString *)email
                               error:(NSError **)error;

/*!
 Send a password reset request asynchronously for a specified email and sets an
 error object. If a user account exists with that email, an email will be sent to 
 that address with instructions on how to reset their password.
 @param email Email of the account to send a reset password request.
 */
+ (void)requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:(NSString *)email;

/*!
 Send a password reset request asynchronously for a specified email and sets an error object.
 If a user account exists with that email, an email will be sent to that address with instructions
 on how to reset their password.
 @param email Email of the account to send a reset password request.
 @param target Target object for the selector.
 @param selector The selector that will be called when the asynchronous request is complete. It should have the following signature: (void)callbackWithResult:(NSNumber *)result error:(NSError **)error. error will be nil on success and set if there was an error. [result boolValue] will tell you whether the call succeeded or not.
 */
+ (void)requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:(NSString *)email
                                          target:(id)target
                                        selector:(SEL)selector;

/*!
 Send a password reset request asynchronously for a specified email.
 If a user account exists with that email, an email will be sent to that address with instructions
 on how to reset their password.
 @param email Email of the account to send a reset password request.
 @param block The block to execute. The block should have the following argument signature: (BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) 
 */
+ (void)requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:(NSString *)email
                                           block:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block;

/** @name Querying for Users */

/*!
 Creates a query for PFUser objects.
 */
+ (PFQuery *)query;


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I don't know why you want to do it, I can't say what method to use is best, but I actually create a custom property of the Installation class called userId, and associate the two that way.  That code looks like the following:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"userId"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

That works for push notifications if that's your goal.  If you really are set on that installationId property being part of the user class, then you could just do what I did, then query the Installation class for matching userIds, although that's  bit circuitous.

Comment: You are correct, the reason I'm doing this is because I want to be able to set a specific user device's `channel` property for push notifications, and I want to do this through cloud code. Hence why I need to associate the User with their respective Installation. When I do what you did above, I get the following error: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'`.

Comment: Okay, so then the way I suggested will work and you don't need to have the installationId be a property of the user class...That means most likely that [PFUser currentUser].objectId is null.  NSLog that to see if that's the case

Comment: Yup, this is what I get when I NSLog it: `Here is PFUser.objectId:'(null)'`. Why is it null, and how can I fix that?

Comment: The reason that's null is because there is no user logged in.

Comment: Ah, turns out I was placing it in a method that ran before the user was logged in, got it in the right spot now, thanks!

Comment: Sorry one last question. This sets the Installations `userId` property to the Users `objectId` property, as a string. How can I make it so that the userId property is a pointer to that user?

Comment: You could conceivably change the "userId" property (which is a string) to say "userObject" (which you'd have to make of type "object"), and that would contain the whole user object in the Installation class, but again without knowing what you want to achieve, it's difficult to say.